# How to display thumbnails for contact / vcf / vcard files in Nautilus or another file browser in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, thumbnails, vcards

Does anyone know of a way to display thumbnails for contact / vcf / vcard files in Nautilus or another file browser in Ubuntu 14.04?[image]

We were trying to put this together but were unsuccessful but received dozens of "I want this too" comments from other users and friends.

What would be a simple way to show a thumbnail for all the vcf / vcard files showing the photo and the contact information for each contact?